# Как программу С++ написанную в visual studio на windows заставить нормально работать в visual studio на Mac OS

Tags: visual-c++, mac, visual-studio-2017

В университете задания делаем в Visual Studio на windows.

Установил себе на компьютер (Mac OS) VS, скачал папку с шаблоном и открыл ее.

Что нужно подключить из модулей, чтобы все работало (отображался язык, запускалась программа и так далее).

Comment: Вы бы создали минимальный пример вида Hello World и показали, с какой ошибкой оно у вас не запускается

Comment: @lDrakonl, вероятно, у него даже solution не открывается.

Comment: Можно попробовать Visual Studio Code для C++ под macOS. Ну и стоит проголосовать за добавление поддержки C++ в Visual Studio for Mac: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/563332-visual-studio-for-mac/suggestions/17141708-support-c-in-visual-studio-for-mac

Comment: @AlexChermenin, разве uservoice не закрыли?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй использовать Parallels для запуска Windows на Mac и в нём установить Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio для MacOS не поддерживает С++. Используйте  Xcode.